# Autoclose Vim plugin – disable “{{”→“{\n\n}” functionality

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How can I disable permanently the following functionality of the autoclose plugin in Vim?

When you press `{{`, it results in:

```
{


}
```

I want it to instead result in `{{ }}`.

Comment: You want to remove it permanently or disable it temporarily?

Comment: Use [the issue tracker](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose/issues).

Comment: Exactly which autoclose plugin are you using? I’m using [`AutoClose--Alves`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoClose--Alves) and I don’t see that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable autocompleting `{` by

```
let g:AutoClosePairs_del = "{"
```

in your `~/.vimrc`. It is also being noted in the manual that `g:AutoClosePairs` can not be set. More details at `:help ac_charstoclose`.

After disabling, you can map your own keys now, for example

```
nnoremap {{ {}<Left>
```

But I would have personally preferred `{` to autocomplete and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd>  <kbd>v</kbd>  followed by `{` to escape auto-completion.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to you ~/.vimrc.before to Turn off auto close feature:

```
let g:autoclose_on = 0
```

Comment: But I don't want to disable the whole functionality of the plugin, just this feature, that the double brace results in a new line between braces